# SQL: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Does anyone of you see the error here? I am searching for it for quite some time now. I do count 19 parameters and 19 values for it and the columns do accept null values:

[image]

```
Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
Error HY093 executing statement:
INSERT INTO 'modx_slides' ('MIGX_formname', 'slider', 'slidelink', 'poster- 
portrait-src', 'poster-landscape-src', 'portrait-src', 'portrait-hres-src', 
'portrait-smup-hres-src', 'landscape-src', 'landscape-hres-src', 'contenttype', 
'headline', 'vartext', 'image-portrait', 'image-landscape', 'resource_id',             
'pos', 'deleted', 'published') VALUES (‘videoItemTpl’, 1, ‘https://test.de', 
‘’, ‘’, ‘’, ‘’, ‘’, ‘image.jpg’, ‘’, 0, ‘Headlineexample’, ‘Sublineexample’, 
‘’, ‘’, 75, 0, 0, 1)
Array
(
    [0] => HY093
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)
```

Comment: have you copy pasted values from somewhere?

Comment: The values are forminputs, which were filled in regularly, why?

Comment: just suspecting commas enclosing it can be the issue. try removing them from code and writing them again

Comment: the code is all working as it's part of a plugin. The values didn't contain commas, I typed in all by myself for testing =/

Comment: I would remove the single quotes from the field names (or replace them by backticks) and change the typographical quotes of the values to regular quotes.

Comment: Just solved it, maybe doublequotes would have helped but see my answer beneath. Thanks anyaways!

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the problem. PDO doesn't accpept regular dashes in fieldnames, after switching regular dashes to lowdashes everything worked fine. Maybe using double quotes would allow using regular dashes but as it's a coreclass of the cms (MODx), I can't change it.